# PHP Session Login Controller

Tags: php, session-storage

I am trying to create a login controller for my website ... in terms of keeping people logged in I've decided to use sessions.

I am currently attempting to create a class that can be referenced when I include the controller file of the sessions. This will allow me to create, authenticate (delete) and update sessions.

```php
<?php

class Session {

    static function start($name, $value) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION[$name] = $value;
        $_SESSION['EXPIRE'] = time() + 10;
    }

    // checking for expire
    static function auth() {
        if (isset($_SESSION['EXPIRE']) && $_SESSION['EXPIRE'] < time()) {
            $_SESSION = array();
            session_destroy();
        }
    }

    static function update($time = 20) {
        if (isset($_SESSION['EXPIRE'])) {
            $_SESSION['EXPIRE'] = time() + $time;
            session_regenerate_id(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Currently it does not set sessions properly. When I try to call the sessions on pages once I set them it does not fetch properly.

The session isn't expiring before I call it because I never call the function that expires it inside the class on the document.

Comment: How are you using the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call your `Session` class as you need to include `session_start()` and you are only having this in the `start` method.

**Option 1**: You would have to call `session_start()` in each page where you want to deal with sessions

**Option 2**: Add a function to your class and call it after your `class` is created and add in there `session_start()` so wherever you include the Session Class `session_start` would already been initialized

Example:

Sessions.php

```
class Session {

    static function init(){
         session_start();
    }
    //rest of your methods...
}

//initialize it
Session::init();
```

page-that-uses-session.php

```
include('Sessions.php');
Session::update();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback! Inside the 'start' function I start the session anyway... but could create another function to start the session separately if it's better?

Comment: Created the 'init' function and called it on the pages that required it, works a charm! Thanks for the suggestion - legend! :)

Answer (score 0):

Better set php session timeout variable in php.ini or from ini_set() function and don't create own $_SESSION['expire'] variable; You can regenerate_session_id() each time when user sent request; Better test user ip address in session. In most projects you have one page on server or only your own pages.

Set user id in session:

```
$_SESSION['userid'] = $loggoed_id_from_db;
// and test
if((int)$_SESSION['userid'] == 0){
    header('Location: logout.php');
    exit;
}else{
    if(empty($_SESSION['ip'])){
        $_SESSION['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }else{
        if($_SESSION['ip'] != $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']){
           header('Location: logout.php');
           exit;
        }
    } 
}
```

And probably you don't start session from class!

Comment: Don't invent things that work quite well from the beginning.